# How to put the output from the console to a swing Gui in java

Tags: java, swing

I am new to java and trying following example. With the code below, I can print all nodes of a XML file. Now I would like to use *Swing* and put it out in a simple *Swing* window.

I understand how to create a window, but how can I connect the console output to a `JTextArea`? I searched for it on Stack Overflow, but did not get the right idea.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    try  
    { 
        File file = new File("dum.xml");
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder(); 
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(file); 
        System.out.println("Root element: "+ document.getDocumentElement().getNodeName()); 
        if (document.hasChildNodes())  
        { 
            printNodeList(document.getChildNodes());
        } 
    }  
    catch (Exception e) 
    { 
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
    } 
} 

private static void printNodeList(NodeList nodeList) 
{ 
    for (int count = 0; count < nodeList.getLength(); count++)
    { 
        Node elemNode = nodeList.item(count); 
        if (elemNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)  
        { 
            // get node name and value 
            System.out.println("\nZeilenname =" + elemNode.getNodeName()+ " [Anfang]");
            System.out.println("Zeileninhalt =" + elemNode.getTextContent()); 
            if (elemNode.hasAttributes())  
            {
                NamedNodeMap nodeMap = elemNode.getAttributes();
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeMap.getLength(); i++)
                {
                    Node node = nodeMap.item(i);
                    System.out.println("Attributname : " + node.getNodeName()); 
                    System.out.println("Attributwert : " + node.getNodeValue()); 
                }
            }
            if (elemNode.hasChildNodes())  
            {
                //recursive call if the node has child nodes
                printNodeList(elemNode.getChildNodes());
            }
            System.out.println("Zeilenname =" + elemNode.getNodeName()+ " [Ende]"); 
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: You don't need to redirect the console to a text area. All you need is to set the text to the Swing component instead of setting the text on the console.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to create the main frame for a Java Swing application following best practices (i.e. use `SwingUtilities#invokeLater(...)` to run your Swing application.

```
public class SwingDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
    
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Demo");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(250,250);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Now you need to add the component to display text. `JLabel`, `JTextField`, and `JTextArea`are the main candidates. Since you mentioned text area, let use that component. For that, all you need to do is add these two lines at the end:

```
    String text = "Hello World!";
    JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea();
    textarea.setText(text);
    f.add(textarea);
    textarea.append("\nI added this later"); // UPDATE
```

You can then modify this sample code so it looks better. For example, you can instead put the text area in a `JPanel` and you could then use layouts to control the placement and size of the panel in order to prevent the text area to expand to the size of the entire `JFrame`. But this minimalist code does exactly what you wanted, which is to set text in a Java Swing GUI.

**UPDATE**: You could use the `append()` method to add lines to your GUI. For example:

```
NamedNodeMap nodeMap = elemNode.getAttributes(); 
for (int i = 0; i < nodeMap.getLength(); i++)  
{ 
    Node node = nodeMap.item(i); 
    textarea.append("\nAttributname : " + node.getNodeName());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. But I still dont understand how can I print out the node names , attributes name and values in the swing window. Shoud I use following statement: textarea.setText(nodeList)?

Comment: @Javabeginner2021 It all depends how you want the output to look. You could iterate thru your node list and set it to a `StringBuilder` and then set its text to the text area. I will suggest to experiment with different methods. If you have specific questions about handing of node lists, you could post a second question. But, to answer your question, no... you can't set the node list directly into the text area. You need to set its contents.

Comment: Please dont understand me wrong. I am very thankful for the quick response and you taking the time. I am not asking to solve the problem but your answers are very vague. So with my knowledge it doesnt really help to fill the gap

Comment: @Javabeginner2021 I appreciate your comments, but the answer is not vague. It is only vague to you because you lack certain knowledge; which I mean no disrespect to you by saying this. In your code, you call methods like `elemNode.getNodeName()` to set the String (text) to the console. You must do the same to set text in the text area. That said, I will make an update to my post to show you how to append text to the same component.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `JTextArea`. Replace all calls to `System.out.println` with `JTextArea.append`. Below code demonstrates.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class XmlSwing {
    private JTextArea textArea;

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createTextArea(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JScrollPane createTextArea() {
        textArea = new JTextArea(20, 40);
        createTextAreaText();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        return scrollPane;
    }

    private void createTextAreaText() {
        try {
            File file = new File("dum.xml");
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = documentBuilder.parse(file);
            textArea.append("Root element: " + document.getDocumentElement().getNodeName() + "\n");
            if (document.hasChildNodes()) {
                printNodeList(document.getChildNodes());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void printNodeList(NodeList nodeList) {
        for (int count = 0; count < nodeList.getLength(); count++) {
            Node elemNode = nodeList.item(count);
            if (elemNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                // get node name and value
                textArea.append("\nZeilenname =" + elemNode.getNodeName() + " [Anfang]\n");
                textArea.append("Zeileninhalt =" + elemNode.getTextContent() + "\n");
                if (elemNode.hasAttributes()) {
                    NamedNodeMap nodeMap = elemNode.getAttributes();
                    for (int i = 0; i < nodeMap.getLength(); i++) {
                        Node node = nodeMap.item(i);
                        textArea.append("Attributname : " + node.getNodeName() + "\n");
                        textArea.append("Attributwert : " + node.getNodeValue() + "\n");
                    }
                }
                if (elemNode.hasChildNodes()) {
                    // recursive call if the node has child nodes
                    printNodeList(elemNode.getChildNodes());
                }
                textArea.append("Zeilenname =" + elemNode.getNodeName() + " [Ende]\n");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new XmlSwing().createAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```

Refer to [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: Thank you very much and God bless you!

Comment: @Javabeginner2021 you can show your appreciation by accepting my answer (or up-voting it, or both :-)